# remove column headers for particular web part in SharePoint web part page

Tags: web-part

I have links list web part where I don't want to show column  headers in the web part . I am using web part page SharePoint 2010  and tried with couple of options like setting summary view instead of current view but its not reflecting once I check in the page. The other option i tried was adding content editor web part and disabling the css but it is removing headers of all the web parts in the page. Please let me know how could i approach to make it work.Thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your Browsers Development Tools, inspect the specific location you are looking to hide and obtain/identify the element name.

Then add a new content editor and edit the html source to include the below:

```
'<style>
HEADER ELEMENT NAME GOES HERE 
{
DISPLAY: none
}
</style>'
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, I guess it didn't let me edit my post because you were doing it at the same time that I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the headers of specific webpart( Link list webpart) the easiest way is using js/jQuery and manipulating the CSS. You need to uniquely identify the header element and then add the attribite(display:none) to make it hidden. Also you can dump your js/jQuery inside a content editor.

Comment: Hi pushpendra i have tried using content editor but it is disabling all the webprts columns in the page. but i need only for particular web part on the page. But how do I use Jquery to do so as you mentioned.

Comment: that i referred in my answer u need to uniquely identify that element and then apply new CSS over it.